# d3-graphviz zoom in and render/focus on 1 node and it is descendant, hide others

Tags: d3.js, graph, graphviz, directed-acyclic-graphs, d3-graphviz

With d3-graphviz and a DAG, how can we render an interactive map, such that when users click on a node, only that node and its descendants and/or ancenstors is visible, while irrelevant nodes are hidden?